# Having Trouble With Discord.py Events

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been using Python for bot development, but recently i faced some problems with events that does not trigger when the action happen.
events like : `on_member_remove` #I tried both# , `on_guild_role_delete` , `on_guild_channel_delete`
I want to know why they don't work , if you know why any of them does not work i will appreciate your help

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, Greedy
from discord import user
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, has_permissions, MissingPermissions
import asyncio


intents = discord.Intents()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", help_command=None, intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="TEST"))
    print('Hello :|')


@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):

    print("on_member_kick Worked")


@bot.event
async def on_guild_role_delete(role):
    print("on_role_delete Worked")

@bot.event
async def  on_guild_channel_delete(channel):
    print("on_channel_delete Worked")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear, this can be fixed if you look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference)

The `on_member_kick`, `on_role_delete` and `on_channel_delete` events simply do not exist.
Possible alternatives are:

- `on_member_remove` (which should've worked according to the docs)
- `on_guild_channel_delete`
- `on_guild_role_delete`

Also, check that you have enabled the intents on the developers page, it may be the cause for the `on_member_remove` event to not work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that didin't work too.